# Angular add data on guard in child routes

Tags: angular, routes, guard

I have a routes configuration like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('../../modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule), data: { rol: 1}, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
    ]
  }
];
```

But when I try to get data param from Guard, it returns undefined. How can I get this data param onto Guard from a child route?

This is how I implement my guard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private estadoService: EstadoService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const ROL = route.data['rol'];
    let checkRol = ROL === this.estadoService.usuarioBloques.id ? true : false;
    return checkRol;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How you implement your `AuthGuard` ?

Comment: Actually, It's working fine because it will check to `path: '', component: .....` that doesn't contain any data.

Comment: Hi again. I just pasted above my Guard code. I will appreciate if you can check it, thanks.

Comment: Can you edit this `StackBlitz`, I'm try with your code and everything just fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2vgaq

Comment: My routes are RouterModule.forChild() and you set yours as .forRoot(). I can't do that, because these routes belong to a router-outlet inside the main router-outlet. Thanks again.